# ValueError: Points cannot contain NaN

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, interpolation, valueerror

Now I'm sure this is just me making a stupid mistake somewhere, but I'm not catching it. Sometimes when I run the code, the plot will show up, and I won't get this error. Other times I get this cute little error message:

```
ValueError    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-acef8d8cfdfb> in <module>()
104 #now to interpolate TCSPC data
105 TCSPCdatadesiredgrid_x, TCSPCdatadesiredgrid_y = np.mgrid[10:321, 0:60.36:0.025]  #60.36 so that 
#it will get to 60.35
--> 106 grid_TCSPC = griddata(TCSPCdatapoints, TCSPCdatavalues, (TCSPCdatadesiredgrid_x, 
TCSPCdatadesiredgrid_y), method='cubic')
107 plt.figure(4)
108 plt.imshow(grid_TCSPC, extent=(0,60.35,10,320), origin='lower', aspect=0.195)


ValueError: Points cannot contain NaN
```

It's also weird, because I have three other codes similar to this one in the program that run just fine each time, so I guess that's how I know this is just a silly mistake:

```
TCSPCdatadesiredgrid_x, TCSPCdatadesiredgrid_y = np.mgrid[10:321, 0:60.36:0.025]  #60.36 so that it 
#will get to 60.35 
grid_TCSPC = griddata(TCSPCdatapoints, TCSPCdatavalues, (TCSPCdatadesiredgrid_x, 
TCSPCdatadesiredgrid_y), method='cubic')
plt.figure(4)
plt.imshow(grid_TCSPC, extent=(0,60.35,10,320), origin='lower', aspect=0.195)
plt.xlabel('Delay time (ns)')
plt.ylabel('Temperature (K)')
plt.title('TCSPC data, interpolated every 1K')
plt.show()
```

Comment: what is TCSPCdatapoints?

Comment: Earlier on in the code I had this: TCSPCdatapoints = np.empty([77280,2])